# Keypress event on chosen single select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I would like to automatically add the selected value when enter key is pressed on chosen jquery single select. So, for that is there any event like keypress which I would use to do something when return key was pressed?

```
<select id="myselect" data-placeholder="Add foods you can buy here." 
style="height:30px; width: 100%" class="chosen-select" onkeypress="handle(event)" >
<option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="blah">
<option>blah blah</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ - there is also an example... It works on drop-down selectors as well.

Comment: Do you mean that whenever a value is selected using either tab/enter on chosen it should get re-added to the chosen dropdown ?

Comment: @MaheshSapkal no.. I don't want that. What i want is to add the selected value to my database on return key press.

Comment: Sanotsh, what is wrong with the behaviour in this fiddle? - http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/XGSxE/

Comment: @AlexPakka I want to do sth when a return key is pressed while the selection is on one of the options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bind the `keyup` event on the jquery chosen dropdown, after chosen in initialized.

Depending upon the version either you need to use `.chosen-container` or `.chzn-container`.

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({});

$(".chosen-container").bind('keyup',function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        $('#myform').submit();
        // or your stuff here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problema by using the code suggesetd by `Mahesh`. If so, use keypress instead:

```
$(".chosen-container").bind('keypress',function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        $('#myform').submit();
        // or your stuff here...
    }
});
```